# VMware View - Netlogon Errors from Linked-Clone Virtual Desktops

Tags: active-directory, vmware-view

I am in the process of deploying View 4.6 using linked clones and non-persistent desktops.  Desktops are set to delete and be recreated when users log out.

I am seeing my domain controller logs fill up with NetLogon errors.   The error IDs that I am seeing are 5722 and 5805 - failure to authenticate errors.  These errors occur after the desktop has been deleted and recreated.  Aside from the error, the desktops appear to provision correctly, and users are able to log in.  The View Composer account has permissions to create and delete desktops in the OU where they are being stored.  I am not running any quickprep scripts.

Are these error messages expected behavior?  Do I need to make any changes to Active Directory or View composer to avoid these errors in the future?